# Use a DNS server to resolve company subdomains and another DNS for other

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, dns

This might be an easy thing, but I couldn't find a solution for it.

We have a Widnows DNS server in company which resolves:

- if the queried name is a subdomain of `mycompany.net` (such as `nexus.mycompany.net` and `oracle.mycompany.net`) returns the configured IPs
- otherwise it delegates to internet based DNS servers (such as `8.8.8.8`).

On my system, I need to lookup subdomains of `mycompany.net` with company DNS, but others through another DNS (for example `80.80.80.80`).

The problem is if I put company-wide DNS server as first item, it will lookup non-local names through its configured DNSes (such as `8.8.8.8`), and if I put it last item, my `80.80.80.80` cannot resolve company subdomains.

I must add that `mycompany.net` is the name registered for our company site, but its subdomains (such as `nexus.mycompany.net` and `oracle.mycompany.net` are just visible in company local network).

How should I configure name resolution, so it looks-up `mycompany.net` subomains through one DNS and others through another?